# What is the function of で in こうした家族の変化で、何が起きているのか?

Tags: grammar, particle-で

> こうした家族の変化**で**、何が起きているのか。([source](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20181228/k10011761401000.html?utm_int=tokushu-new_contents_list-items_003))

The で indicates the "cause"(what is happening because of the transformation?) or the "location"(what is happening in the transformation?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an alternative way of saying `こうした家族の変化によって、何が起きているのか。`　(cause). It's not impossible to interpret it as "location" (for example, `こうした幼虫から成虫への変化で異常が起きることがある` would be "location"), but I think overall (given the context etc) it's quite clear that it's the former in this case.